# Is it possible to obtain permanent residency under an L-1B visa?

Tags: working-visas, citizenship, usa, pr, l1-visa

Is it possible to obtain permanent residency under an L-1B visa? I was under the impression that L-1B has no dual intent, hence it would be difficult to adjust status to become US permanent residents. Please explain further and feel free to correct me if I am wrong. I want to ask about the specifics of obtaining permanent residency under an L-1B visa. Thank you.

Comment: L supports dual intent almost the same way that H does.  See [this overview](https://www.temple.edu/isss/international/DualIntent.htm) and compare [8 CFR 214.2(l)(16)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/214.2#l_16) and [8 USC 1184(b) aka INA 214(b)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1184#b).  Not posting as an answer because I don't know how/if the L process affects the I-140 process.